# CMS for isolated websites

Tags: software-development, cms

I'm evaluating different CMS platforms to find the best fit for our company. We'd like it to be a. Net-based platform because that is what we are comfortable working in.

Basically, we will have our primary website (www.example.com) hosted on a cloud platform (probably Azure). We will also host a secondary website on our own servers (apps.example.com) that will be used to host intranet applications for our staff as well as forms used by the general public to buy our products. The reason they need to be kept separate from one another is that the public website requires 24/7 uptime and our secondary website needs access to our database server.

The challenge is that we want the primary website to be built on a CMS platform as its content will change more frequently, but we also want some pages on our secondary website to pull their content from the same CMS.

What I'm interested in is the ability to define generic content "snippets" in the CMS and have the secondary web application be able to reference the CMS instance and use these content snippets where needed. Whether this would be achieved via a web service call or something else is up for discussion.

The DNN platform seems like it could be a good fit as it's a great CMS tool but also serves as a platform for building custom functionality on top of it.

I'm really just seeking advice from others who may have had experience with a scenario similar to this or if there is a CMS tool out there that provides this functionality out of the box.

Thanks

Comment: Is .Net required or only preferred?

Comment: Preferred, however I would be open to suggestions based on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Check out a shared content repository. For example [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/). It helps to centralise shared content and sync it to your different output channels / sites.

However you have to write / implement an extension in every output channel (well at least if it is a different software platform, e.g. Drupal, DNN, Hippo) that communicates with your Shared Content Repository.

We tested Contentful for a customer in a prototype that should centralise content from over 50 sites and push/pull it back to them at will. What I learned is that a shared content repository could fill in the gap you mentioned.